# How to enforce entity dependencies in SOA environment - build / download?

Tags: web-services, constraints, soa, foreign-key-relationship, data-management

When establishing several modular and independent services, I am challenged with dependencies / stored relationships between entities. Consider Job Position and Employee. In my system, the Employee's Assignment is linked (URI) to the Job Position.

For our application, the Job Positions would be managed by a separate service than the Employee service, which leads to the challenge of constraints to prevent inadvertent removal of a Job Position if an employee is already matched to that position.

I've designed a custom solution leveraging a Registry (which should have dependency details, etc.) and enforce a paradigm across the inter-dependent services, however it is complex. In the SOA environment, how could one manage these inter-dependencies?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some ways your question could be rephrased as "How to enforce referential integrity in SOA environment". Well the answer is you can't. That's kind of a by-product of the *Autonomous* in the [tenets of SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-orientation).

So almost by definition, the Job Position in the Employee service is not the same thing as the Job Position in the Job Position service. This is actually a good thing. Even though both services define Job Position, they do so from two different capabilities, and are free to develop and evolve their capability as needs arise.

So, hard constraints on the removal of data within one service boundary based on the existence of similar data inside another service boundary are just not possible (or even desirable).

This is all very well, but then how do you avoid the situation where Employees may be "matched" to a Job Position which has changed in some way, either via removal or update?

Well, services can be interested in changes to other services. And in these situations, services can become consumers of each other. It's fairly obvious the Employee capability would be interested in changes to the Job Position capability.

[Events](http://www.eaipatterns.com/EventMessage.html) are actually a fairly well used design pattern for this scenario. If a business action results in a change the data of a service, that service can publish an event message which describes the change. Other services can become consumers of this type of event and can handle it in their own fashion. Because eventing is usually implemented with a pub-sub semantic, any service capability which so desires can subscribe to the event.

In your example, the event which could be published if a job position was deleted could be defined as (using C#):

```
class JobPositionRemoved
{
    int JobPositionId { get; set; }
    string JobPositionName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

How a consumer of this event actually handles it (what action would be taken by the consumer) is another question and would depend on the capability of the consumer. As an example, your Employee service could gather a list of the Employees with this job position and flag them for review, or add them to a queue for "job position reassignment".

Your event could even include a field called `int ReplacedByJobPosition` which would enable consumers to automatically update any capability that depended on the removed job position.

As long as your event is delivered across a fault-tolerant transport (such as message queuing), you can be fairly confident that while you won't have referential integrity between your service capabilities, your system as a whole should become [consistent eventually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency).

By using events in this way, you also avoid the need for a centralized registry of inter-dependencies (which sounds like a nasty idea). Each service is responsible for publishing events about changes to it's own data, and dependencies are defined by services consuming events from each other.

Hope this is helpful.

**EDIT**

In answer to your comment - while I can see the benefit of having another service taking care of the position:reassignment problem and I don't see any massive problems with this, there are a few considerations.

One of the reasons why service boundaries and business capability boundaries are a natural fit is that when you change a business capability (eg a change in Billing procedure) it does not generally impact other business capabilities (CRM/Finance/etc). By introducing shared services you're coupled to more than one capability, your service doesn't have well defined boundaries, and as a result has a higher cost of ownership as it will need to be changed a lot.

Additionally you could argue that the consumer of a business event (eg, JobPositionRemoved) should take responsibility for the entire handling of that event.

The handling of the event may well trigger a subsequent event to be published (such as ReviewTaskCreatedForEmployeeChange) which can then be handled by another consumer (eg a workflow tool) if desired.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, for the response. This helps a tremendously. The event-based approach to cross-service referential integrity sounds like the way to go. A follow-up question: What are your thoughts on establishing a shared service to manage the "Position:Assignment" relationship (if our rules prohibit the removal of a position if an employee is assigned to the position. Given that in our system neither a "Job Location" or "Employee" would be deleted, the references the shared service would have to Locations/Employees would be "references" rather than "constraints". Any thoughts? thanks again!

Comment: Glad you found useful. Please see update to my answer.